# Homework: Java IO Streaming and String manipulation

Tags: java, string

In Java,
I need to read lines of text from a file and then reverse each line, writing the reversed version into another file. I know how to read from one file and write to another. What I don't know how to do is manipulate the text so that "This is line 1" would be written into the second file as "1 enil si sihT"

Comment: The best person to ask would be your TA or professor.

Comment: Still a valid question, even on stack overflow

Comment: No, it's a terrible, lazy, worthless question, the badness of which is exceeded only by the answers from people who should know better.

Comment: Which, on one hand, isn't a reason for downvoting. On the other hand I'm more than agreeing with you that you must not ask a question before you've googled for at least 15 minutes and have checked the javadoc.

Comment: (I meant downvoting peoples answers)

Comment: @Bozho: I disagree. Why Google 15 minutes when you can have the answer in 1? Plus, sometimes google is useful when you already know what you're looking for, that's not always the case with new programmers ( or lazy :P ) => http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16353/stackoverflow-for-the-lazy-newbie-developer

Comment: You know what, I'm going to downvote the everliving CAKE out of answers that make bad students worse by feeding their worst instincts. It's my new mission in life.

Comment: I'm under the impression that the title on "downvote" is "The answer is not useful", not "There is a possibility that wrong moral points are taken".

Comment: LOL @Jonathan: I guess everyone has right to do what ever he wants with his rep points. :) :)

Comment: @Oscar - http://www.google.com/search?hl=en-GB&q=java+string+reverse&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_en___BG265&ie=UTF-8&aq=0&oq=java+string+rever in this case, I'm not agreeing with you :)

Comment: The optimal strategy for maximizing one's pay and professional standing is to give excellent, polished answers to lazy students and no or terrible answers to competing programmers. I'm not saying I do this or recommend doing it, I'm just saying.

Comment: My point is, give the guy a break. If he have a programming question and he want a good answer SO should be the right place to ask. Probably some of you guys born programming or make the "Hello Wold" before walk,  but some of us learn very very late ( > 18 ). If this question is TOO EASY for you, just skip it!. In my case I remember how it felt when you don't have a clue! The OP shows interest by stating what have already fulfilled in is program. Take it easy!

Comment: He *doesn't* have a programming question! It's a **homework** question. That's an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 2):

If this is homework, it would be better for you to understand how are data stored into the string it self.

A string may be represented as an array of characters

```
String line =  // read line ....;
char [] data = line.toCharArray();
```

To reverse an array you have to swap the positions of the elements. The first in the last, the last in the first and so on.

```
int l = data.length;
char temp;

temp         = data[0];      // put the first element in "temp" to avoid losing it.
data[0]      = data[l - 1]; // put the last value in the first;
data[l - 1]  = temp;         // and the first in the last.
```

Continue with the rest of the elements ( hint use a loop )  in the array and then create a new String with the result:

```
String modifiedString = new String( data ); // where data is the reversed array.
```

If is not ( and you really just need to have the work done ) use:

[StringBuilder.reverse()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29)

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(theString);
return buffer.reverse().toString();
```

Comment: @Nick: if your surround your code snippet with pre and code tags, you'll get better readability (and possibly more upvotes :).

Answer (score 2):

since these are homeworks you are probably interested in your own implementation of `reverse` method.

The **naive version** visits the string backwards (from the last index to the index 0) while copying it in a [StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
public String reverse(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

for example the String "hello":

```
H e l l o 
0 1 2 3 4  // indexes for charAt()
```

the method start by the index 4 ('o') then the index 3 ('l') ... until 0 ('H').

Answer (score 1):

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder(textLine).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided answers all suggest using an already existing method, which is sound advice and usually more effective than writing your own.

Depending on the assignment, however, your teacher might expect you to write a method of your own. If that is the case, try using a `for` loop to walk through the string character by character, only instead of counting from zero and up, start counting from the last character index and down to zero, consecutively building the reversed string.

Answer (score 1):

While we're feeding horrible, finished answers to the poor student, we might as well whet his appetite for the bizarre. If strings were guaranteed to be reasonably short and CPU time was no object, this is what I'd code:

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
   if (str.length() == 0) return ""; 
   else return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
```

(OK, I admit it: my current favorite language is Clojure, a Lisp!)

**BONUS HOMEWORK:** Figure out if, how and why this works!

Comment: Fun solution, except for the performance issue of string concatenation, which should really use a StringBuilder

Comment: Definitely, that's why I qualified "CPU time no object" :) Using a StringBuilder would have resulted in lengthier code though. That's not what I was optimizing for.

Comment: And unfortunately the stack overflow potential is the far more serious problem. :(

Answer (score -1):

[java.lang.StringBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) has a [reverse](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse()) method.